# Отправка двух форм по очереди (php, ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, form

Пытаюсь отправить две формы по очереди.
Все работает, но задача стоит в том, чтобы из первой формы передать параметры во вторую. 
Вот код:
file.php:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function ajax() { //Ajax отправка формы
         var msg = $("#form").serialize();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send.php",
            data: msg,
            success: function(data) {
              $('#form2').submit();
            },
            error:  function(xhr, str){
                      alert("Возникла ошибка!");
            }
          });
        }
    </script>

<form method="POST" id="form" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="ajax()">
<legend>Test From</legend>
<label for="name">Name:</label><input id="name" name="name" value="" type="text">
<label for="email">Surname:</label><input id="surname" name="surname" value="" type="text">
<input value="Send" type="submit">
</form>

<form name='form2' id='form2' action='example.com/script.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='val1' value=  '<?= $fullname; ?>'>
</form>
```

Файл send.php:

```
<?
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$fullname = "$name $surname";

?>
```

Как передать во вторую форму переменную `$fullname`?
Получается что форма `form2` загружается тогда же когда и первая, как сделать последовательно?

Comment: Интересно, а зачем вообще такое извращение? Во вторую форму сразу Имя Фамилию передать нельзя из инпутов склеенные яваскриптом?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский К сожалению, опыта в javascript и ajax нету. А для объяснения извращений: первая форма обрабатывает введенные пользователем данные, вторая отправляет на платежный шлюз. Чтобы человеку не нажимать несколько раз сабмиты. Про имя и фамилию привел схематичный пример. Можете объяснить что вы имели в виду?

Comment: @tereshok Так а зачем миллион форм? Я так и понял, что вы что-то валидируете. НО....Даже если вы плохо знаете яваскрипт, почему бы вам сразу не отправлять в данные в `example.com/script.php` ? В котором, если вы так хотите валидировать, можете использовать функции методы валидации из других файлов php. А так вы только зря лишний раз дергаете сервер. А если валидацию не прошел `return false` с ошибкой вам в помощь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так example.com/script.php это уже платежный шлюз, к которому соответственно доступа нет.

Comment: @tereshok Ааа... То есть это `example.com/script.php` вообще не на ваш сайт ссылка, а на сервис внешний? Если так, опять же, зачем стопицот запросов и гонение данных туда сюда, если после прохождения валидации можно сразу по нужному адресу из php кода все и отправить?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Посоветуйте, как же тогда это сделать, потому как не вижу правильного решения. Логика в том, что когда юзер нажимает на кнопку, происходит запись в БД, после этого юзера надо направить на платежный шлюз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как передать во вторую форму переменную $fullname?

Ее надо передавать через ответ от ajax запроса первой формы. Файл send.php должен вернуть эти данные:

```
<?
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$fullname = "$name $surname";
echo $fullname;
```

И соответственно их надо принять на стороне js и подставить во вторую форму перед ее отправкой:

```
            success: function(data) {
              $('input[name="val1"]').val(data);
              $('#form2').submit();
            },
```

А тут

```
<input type='hidden' name='val1' value=  '<?= $fullname; ?>'>
```

вывода `$fullname` не должно быть, так как на момент вывода страницы с формами пользователю этой переменной еще не существует:

```
<input type='hidden' name='val1'>
```